# Can I actually save several cursor positions using ANSI escape sequences?

Tags: bash, ansi-escape, cursor-position

According to [this source](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), these are the operations that can be done about the cursor :

```
- Position the Cursor:
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
  puts the cursor at line L and column C.
- Move the cursor up N lines:
  \033[<N>A
- Move the cursor down N lines:
  \033[<N>B
- Move the cursor forward N columns:
  \033[<N>C
- Move the cursor backward N columns:
  \033[<N>D

- Clear the screen, move to (0,0):
  \033[2J
- Erase to end of line:
  \033[K

- Save cursor position:
  \033[s
- Restore cursor position:
  \033[u
```

So you can save the cursor position, using `\033[s`, and then restore it using `\033[u`. But what if I want to save several cursor positions?

For example, let's say I want to save two cursor positions, **and then** restoring them. Values will get erased right? So my question is : Is there a way, using ANSI escaped sequences *or not*, to save several cursor positions to restore them later in bash?

Comment: You can save the cursor position within your code using `"\033[s"` -- but consider using offsets from a chosen line of output and updating the output rather than a using saved position. Why? If you program outputs an additional line somewhere along the way and you are returning to a fixed position with an ANSI escape, you are now returning one line off. Using a fixed line and offsets, you simply overwrite the output with your formatted data on the next update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI terminal does not have a memory of cursor positions. If you need to anything complicated like that, you will have to keep track of the cursor position yourself.

That's a lot of work and tricky to get right. You're much better off using `ncurses`.

Comment: Actually, it's okay if I can't do it. I was just curious to know if it was possible. Thanks!